# jacobian determinant for coordinate transformation

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have two curves $y=x^2$, $y=2x^2$ in one $x,y$ coordinate system and limit $0\leq x\leq 1$. 
What I want to do is transforming this two curves to a new $u,v$ coordinate system. In this new coordinate system. these two curves are straight line.
How could I find the transformation component? $(u=f(x,y), v=g(x,y))$

For parallel curve like $y=x^2$, $y=x^2+1$, it's easy to transform to two parallel straight line in the new coordinate system. I just set $u=x,v=y-x^2$ to achieve that. However, it's hard for me to find the transformation component for non-parallel curve.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.